# Summary Formula ReportBuilder

Tags: lightning-experience, reporting, dashboard, report-builder

I want to summarize the following information from a report I was given:

[image: Report with grouped by borrower name and closed current year count]

I want to ***make a summary column*** that does the following:
**IF a row/borrower name has a nonzero entry in both the "0" and "1" column, then the summary column should mark that row with a 1 in the summary column for that row. If the conditions are not met, then enter zero in the summary column for that row.**

The highlighted rows are the rows that should have a summary column value of 1.

I am very new to reportbuilding and I have been given some weird reports to improve upon; I want write a summary formula using this logic, but I do not know how I go about doing that. Here is what I have so far:

[image]

I appreciate all suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new summary formula:

```
IF(ColumnGroupingField:MIN == 0, 1, 0)
```

Replace ColumnGroupingField with the field that you're grouping your rows by.
Appending the :MIN to this field will pull the smallest value in the rowcounts for that grouping. Ff the smallest of the two values in this grouping is equal to 0, it will return 0 and 1 otherwise.

You can also format how this value is displayed under the **FORMAT** tab in the summary formula editor:

[image]

**Here's how the results look from my test:**
[image]

Notice a *New Formula* field was added above the record count in each grouping

So in your case, the *Borrower Name* would replace the first column in the image and the *Closed Current Year*'s formula field will be used for the formula. Note that this will be different than the actual api name of this field and should be selected using the Fields tab of the Full Formula Editor

Comment: thank you! i was playing around with this. I get this error when I put the the row grouping field into this formula:

"field MtgPlanner_CRM__Transaction_Property__c.MtgPlanner_CRM__Borrower_Name__c:MIN does not exist. Check spelling."

However, when I put in the column grouping into this field, the formula has no syntax errors, and actually runs the formula (albeit the formula not working with numbers I wanted as it is using the column grouping rather than row grouping)

Comment: I updated the answer to be column grouping instead of row grouping. However, from your initial question it seems like the column grouping is indeed what should be used as you'll be checking the values of the two columns for every row.

Comment: Note that the formula editor for summary formulas in report builder does not refer to api names of fields in salesforce like you specified: `MtgPlanner_CRM__Transaction_Property__c.MtgPlanner_CRM__Borrower_Name__c`


Instead select the correct field in Full Editor on the left hand panel under the _Fields_ tab's _Grouping Fields_